# how to show the image from top to bottom using css3

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to display an image from bottom to top using css3 animation??
The full image should need to be displayed only at the end of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pseudo element for this (hover gray area):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/300/300);
  overflow:hidden;
}
div:before {
  transition: all 1.2s;
  background: gray;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
div:hover:before{
  top:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```